# How to deduct from a total value using multiple editTexts in Java

Tags: java, android

I am developing a game where I need to deduct from a set value. The set value is say $10,000 and I have five editTexts where users can input quantities and then those quantities are multiplied by different $ values, for instance, 2 * $400, 1 * $600, 3 * $100...  and then I want those totals deducted from the set value as they are entered so the player can see how much of the 10,000 is remaining.

I have been able to accomplish this with a single editText using onTextChangedListener.

I have not tested the below code but in my app it is something like this.

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
                                  int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
                              int before, int count) {

        BigDecimal totalValue = new BigDecimal("10000");
        mTotalValueTextView.setText(totalValue);
        if (s.length() > 0) {
            BigDecimal quantityEntered = new BigDecimal(s.toString());
            BigDecimal amountPurchased = quantityEntered.multiply(new BigDecimal("400"));
            BigDecimal newTotalValue = totalValue.subtract(amountPurchased);
            mTotalValueTextView.setText(newTotalValue + "");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
```

In this case if the user enters the quantity 1, the total value will immediately drop by 400, the quantity 2 by 800, and so on. The problem is that I do not know how to have another editText and onTextChangedListener subtract from the same value. Maybe there is another approach I should be taking? It's late when I'm writing this, let me know if there are any problems with my original code and I will fix.

Here is the activity I was originally working on. I tried to simplify in the above example, but maybe this will help.

```
package oneonanyone.com.fantasybasketball_1onany1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import oneonanyone.com.fantasybasketball_1onany1.DataModel.Player;

public class MatchupActivity extends Activity {

    private Player[] mPlayers;
    private TextView mPlayerName;
    private TextView mPlayerValue;
    private TextView mPlayerRemainingValue;
    private TextView mPoints;
    private TextView mRebounds;
    private TextView mAssists;
    private TextView mSteals;
    private TextView mBlocks;

    private TextView mOpponentName;
    private TextView mOpponentValue;
    private TextView mOpponentRemainingValue;
    private TextView mOpponentPoints;
    private TextView mOpponentRebounds;
    private TextView mOpponentAssists;
    private TextView mOpponentSteals;
    private TextView mOpponentBlocks;

    private EditText mPtEditText;
    private EditText mRebEditText;
    private EditText mAssEditText;
    private EditText mStlEditText;
    private EditText mBlkEditText;

    private Button mAcceptMatchButton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_matchup);

        mPlayerName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playerNameTextView);
        mPlayerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playerValueTextView);
        mPlayerRemainingValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.remainingCapTextView);
        mPoints = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pointsTextView);
        mRebounds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reboundsTextView);
        mAssists = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.assistsTextView);
        mSteals = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stealsTextView);
        mBlocks = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.blocksTextView);

        mOpponentName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.opponentTextView);
        mOpponentValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.opponentValue);
        mOpponentRemainingValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.opponentCap);
        mOpponentPoints = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.opponentPoints);
        mOpponentRebounds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.opponentReb);
        mOpponentAssists = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.opponentAssists);
        mOpponentSteals = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.opponentSteals);
        mOpponentBlocks = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.opponentBlocks);

        mPtEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ptEditText);
        mRebEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rebEditText);
        mAssEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.assEditText);
        mStlEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.stlEditText);
        mBlkEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.blkEditText);

        mAcceptMatchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.acceptMatchButton);



        final Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();



        mPlayerRemainingValue.setText("Funds Remaining: $" + extras.getString("PLAYER_CAP"));

        mPlayerName.setText(extras.getString("PLAYER_NAME"));
        mPlayerValue.setText("Price: $" + extras.getString("PLAYER_VALUE"));
        mPoints.setText("Points " + extras.getString("PLAYER_POINTS"));
        mRebounds.setText("Rebounds " + extras.getString("PLAYER_REBOUNDS"));
        mAssists.setText("Assists " + extras.getString("PLAYER_ASSISTS"));
        mSteals.setText("Steals " + extras.getString("PLAYER_STEALS"));
        mBlocks.setText("Blocks " + extras.getString("PLAYER_BLOCKS"));

        mOpponentName.setText(extras.getString("OPPONENT_NAME"));
        mOpponentValue.setText("Price: $" + extras.getString("OPPONENT_VALUE"));
        mOpponentRemainingValue.setText("Funds Remaining: $" + extras.getString("OPPONENT_CAP"));
        mOpponentPoints.setText("Points " + extras.getString("OPPONENT_POINTS"));
        mOpponentRebounds.setText("Rebounds " + extras.getString("OPPONENT_REBOUNDS"));
        mOpponentAssists.setText("Assists " + extras.getString("OPPONENT_ASSISTS"));
        mOpponentSteals.setText("Steals " + extras.getString("OPPONENT_STEALS"));
        mOpponentBlocks.setText("Blocks " + extras.getString("OPPONENT_BLOCKS"));









        mPtEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                BigDecimal dynamicCapValue = new BigDecimal(extras.getString("PLAYER_CAP"));

                mPlayerRemainingValue.setText("Funds Remaining: $" + dynamicCapValue);

                if (s.length() > 0) {

                    BigDecimal input = new BigDecimal(s.toString());

                    BigDecimal ptsPurchased = input.multiply(new BigDecimal("400"));

                    BigDecimal initialCap = new BigDecimal(extras.getString("PLAYER_CAP"));

                   dynamicCapValue = initialCap.subtract(ptsPurchased);


                    mPlayerRemainingValue.setText("Funds Remaining: $" + dynamicCapValue);

                }



            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


            }
        });

        mRebEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                mPlayerRemainingValue.setText("Funds Remaining: $" + extras.getString("PLAYER_CAP"));


                if (s.length() > 0) {
                    BigDecimal input = new BigDecimal(s.toString());

                    BigDecimal rebPurchased = input.multiply(new BigDecimal("800"));

                    BigDecimal initialCap = new BigDecimal(extras.getString("PLAYER_CAP"));

                    BigDecimal remainingValue = initialCap.subtract(rebPurchased);

                    mPlayerRemainingValue.setText("Funds Remaining: $" + remainingValue);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });




    }





    public BigInteger getDollarAmount(){

        String ptQuantity = mPtEditText.getText().toString();
        BigInteger ptQuantity1 = new BigInteger(ptQuantity);
        BigInteger ptDollarAmount = new BigInteger("400");
        BigInteger ptTotalDollarAmount = ptQuantity1.multiply(ptDollarAmount);


        return ptTotalDollarAmount;

    }




}
```

Comment: Do you want to sum the value of several EditText?

Comment: I thought about summing the value of the EditTexts and then subtracting it from the total value, but I would like to be able to see each editText individually being subtracted from the total value as each editText value is entered. I do not know if summing them first would be able to accomplish this.

Comment: Can you send the activity completely?

Comment: Yes, but it is somewhat different than how I wrote the question. I tried to simplify.

Comment: Incredible, thank you for your response! I think I see the logic of your answer but I am having trouble implementing it. Do I still need to add a new TextWatcher for each editText?

Comment: Yes if  you want to sum and calculate total by changing the `EditText`s. And No if you want calculate total by some thing like a `Button` ~~~ You can call `sumInputs(...)` method every where you want calculate total.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it and let you know!

Comment: mark my answer accepted, if it's useful ~~~ and if it's not so good tell me

Comment: Apologies, yes, I think it is useful, and I appreciate your reply. I had not accepted your answer yet because I have not successfully implemented your solution yet. I have been working on other parts of my app, and have been planning on revisiting the issue soon. I did not mean to leave you hanging. Apologies if my lack of communication has been poor forum etiquette.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salam!

This method return you that need as double:

```
public double sumInputs(double totalValue) {
    EditText[] inputs = {mPtEditText, mRebEditText,
            mAssEditText, mStlEditText, mBlkEditText};

    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
        sum = sum + Double.parseDouble(inputs[i].getResources().toString());

    return totalValue - sum;
}
```

So you can set this `TextWatcher` to your `EditText`:

```
TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        sumInputs(400);
    }
};
```

**Note:** 400 is totalValue

---

tell me if you need more help ...